# Iterating over text without string or array functions

Tags: c++, for-loop, iteration

First off this is a homework assignment:

I need to iterate over piece of text using only for loops to find the length of the text. We are not allowed to use string functions or array functions.

I am clueless on how to do this.

Can anyone please provide a basic example? I have seen several examples on how to do this on here and cplusplus.com forums, but none of them used for loops.

Comment: So what have you seen? Can you post some of the code?

Comment: Aw. This is really a breakdown in the programming teaching system. IMHO, teachers should always encourage the use of library functions, especially the standard library functions. And you should, at all times, if possible.

Comment: @MarkGarcia This is a simpler example than most, but this is common in teaching. Imagine, if you could use `std::list` would you even learn how to write, consequently understand, linked lists?

Comment: @MarkGarcia For a "Intro to programming for [physicists, mathematicians,...]" course, I would agree with you, but in a CS or software engineering course, you have to learn how those library functions work, and trying to implement them yourself is always the best method for that.

Comment: @us2012 Still, they all teach those topics in a should-do-it-all-by-yourself manner. Why not teach the concepts first, on how they work? Then on how to use the libraries. The last thing they should make students do is to implement those topics, especially as homeworks.

Comment: @MarkGarcia - Just started data structures. We're starting out with with hashing. Everything has to be ours. My professor agrees with us2012 - full understanding comes from implementing. Same pro two semesters ago in structured methodology wouldn't let us use any standard search algos. I actually like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do:

```
char str[256] = "some text here";
int length = 0;
int i = 0;
char c;
for(c = str[i]; c != '\0'; ++i)
{
   length++;
}
```

But please.. do not use stack overflow as a shortcut in doing your homework. You still need to spend time learn all the programming basics. Only ask here if you encounter very specific problem

Comment: Thanks gerrytan and everyone else. I spent an hour or so searching online after I couldn't find an answer in my book. I was forgetting that you could use an array or string, just not the built in functions. I had it in my head I couldn't use string or array's at all.

Comment: For information only, c++ string is completely different than c string. In c string is basically array of characters (eg: char* or char[]) whereas c++ provides a class called std::string complete with all the utilities functions.